# Let MS Project decide which worker to assign

Tags: ms-project

Say I have a project with multiple tasks and two workers available.
Each worker can work on each task, some tasks need both workers, others only need one worker.
How can I do this in MS Project?
If a task should be done by one worker, this one worker should do the entire task.

I have defined all the tasks and both workers.
I know how to assign a specific worker to a task, but don't know how to say "use this OR this worker for the task".

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but there is no "auto-assignment" in Project. You could create a generic resource with a Max Unit value of 200%. Assign the resource at 100% for tasks that only need one worker and 200% for those tasks that need both workers.

You may still get overallocations and you can use Project's leveling feature to help alleviate them.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the approach I've been using instead. Surprises me that this doesn't exist. Now there's no way to assure that a task is performed entirely by the same person.

Comment: Many Project users want (or assume) that Project can optimize resource usage by re-assigning resources but no such algorithm exists and its unlikely it ever will, there are just two many variables. You can identify who works on what task, but to do so you'll have to individually assign resources.